# Wrong position imgAreaSelect plugin in bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with imgAreaSelect plugin in Bootstrap.
I set parent in initializing imgAreaSelect to prevent scroll moving area :

```
 thumb.imgAreaSelect({
 handles: true,
 aspectRatio: '1:1',
 fadeSpeed: 300,
 parent: "#thumbBox"
 })
```

and this is my html :

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="font-weight:bold;">
                    Upload your picture and crop it.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div id="thumbBox">
                        <img id="thumb" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

whene I trying to select an area,ImgAreaSelect selects an area outside the picture but points ( I mean x1,x2 etc) are exactly that I want(the functionality works correct but in interface there is problem).
In smaller devices's,ImgAreaSelect interface is nit but in some situation it mess up !
I used to search a lot but i didn't find anything useful.
How can i fix this problem ?

**UPDATE :**
I solved this My self...
Refer to this link :
[github](https://github.com/orgsync/imgareaselect/commit/e62ee51ace2b264fa4f6d1b5e21f9c0f67e391c6)

We must remove these lines from code :

```
/* Also check if any of the ancestor elements has fixed position */ 
        if ($p.css('position') == 'fixed')
           position = 'fixed';
```

And we must position relative the parent box that we initialized ourselves( parent: "#thumbBox").

Comment: Great, this fix imgAreaSelect plugin also in a foundation reveal. Thank you

Comment: Where do you remove those lines? Having the same problem

Comment: Is there a reason this fix has not been accepted in imgAreaSelect?

Comment: Did you fix this issue? It's still completely in the wrong position :( any help would be welcome!

Comment: Did you remove the peace of code from the js ?

Comment: This works for me in nyroModal too! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mean the parent div of Image that you want to use image area select on it , must be position relative .

```
 <div id="thumbBox" style="position:relative;">
     <img id="thumb" class="img-responsive" />
   </div>
```

And We must remove these lines from jquery.imageareaselect.js :

```
/* Also check if any of the ancestor elements has fixed position */ 
        if ($p.css('position') == 'fixed')
           position = 'fixed';
```

Answer (score 8):

Had same problem.
solution was:

```
parent:$('.modal-content')
```

you need to set modal content as parent not image container.

Comment: I've tested all the solutions proposed in the comments, this one worked for me and didn't required the modification of any of the libraries

Comment: This worked for me too. This should be picked as the right answer since it is so simple to implement and also makes intuitive sense.

Answer (score 3):

There are several scenarios that bootstrap.css can affect your imgareaselect.  For me setting box-sizing:content-box on the image fixed my problem.

```
<img id="cartPhoto" class="cartImageThumb" style="box-sizing:content-box; -moz-box-sizing:content-box; -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;">
```

I prefer to overwrite the css inline vs modifying the bootstrap.css file because those chan it can affect the whole system.

If you run into issues with bootstrap.css affecting your code, comment out sections of bootstrap.css until you find which style is affecting you.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<div><img id="cropimage" /></div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function () {
 $('#cropimage').imgAreaSelect({ handles: true, parent: "cropimage", maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200, aspectRatio: '4:3' });
});
```

**SOLUTION:**

**Use "parent" option to fix the imgAreaSelect to a parent div/window.**

Answer (score 1):

People who are having trouble with this in combination with **Bootstrap 2**

Go to bootstrap.css and comment out the following line

```
img {
    width: auto\9;
    height: auto;
    /* max-width: 100%; DISABLE FOR IMGAREASELECT */
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

Comment: Of course this solves the issue but is there any way to use imgAreaSelect with max-width? I think there must be any way that I can select on a resized preview image but after calculate the right coordinates. I just not can doit. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried it but it's not simple math. You would have to know the amount of pixels the image is scaled and apply that amount to the imgareaselect afterwards.. What i've done now is when a user uploads an image it's rescaled first.. And then the user can use imgareaselect, But i first rescale it so it fits every screen

Comment: +1 although it is really a "not good" solution, it's the only I could find that would actually solve (at least temporarily the problem). I'll still keep looking for a better solution, but so far that's it, thanks.

Comment: You could edit the code in imgareaselect, so that it gives a class to the <img> container..

Then you can use img.imgareaselect {max-width: auto;} ( untested )

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was looked for a solution on this thread, trying all options.
But, when I read the documentation I found this 2 properties:

http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html

```
imageHeight - True height of the image (if scaled with the CSS width and height properties) 
imageWidth - True width of the image (if scaled with the CSS width and height properties)
```

So, there is no need to change any code of js or css.
The only thing to do is set these 2 properties with the real size of the image.

Something like this:

```
var image = $("#image");

image.imgAreaSelect({
    imageHeight: image[0].naturalHeight,
    imageWidth: image[0].naturalWidth
});
```